# Sewage pump sounds like running dry

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, basement, pump, sewer

We have a sewage pump in our basement. We didn’t install it but inherited it with the purchase of the house. I believe the basement was updated in 2014 with a bathroom, hence the sewage pump. The last few weeks it’s been making a noise when no water has been flushed/drained at all in the house. It’s not constant and only lasts about 4-6 seconds but I don’t understand why it would be doing this. Any ideas? 
I don’t have a lot of knowledge on sewage pumps, so any insight is helpful!
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Check the sump where the pump is located.  It's likely getting a trickle of water from somewhere, filling very slowly until it trips the float switch and pumps the water out.  You may have a leaky stool, water seepage from under the floor, a dripping faucet, a de/humidifier, or condensing furnace draining into it.  Your next steps, if any, depend on where the water is coming from.

Comment: We do have a water line from our furnace but I believe that is from our air conditioner. Is it typical that the sewage pump would second as a sump pump? I’ve checked all faucets, and our toilets do not run or refill unnecessarily, so my only other option would be water seeping in from the ground? If that’s the case, then this isn’t an issue? It runs fine when the toilet is flushed or the shower is run.

Comment: Also a possibility that effluent is seeping back through the pump because of a check valve not functioning properly or not having one installed at al.

Comment: @Mike A high efficiency gas furnace may drain condensate whenever in use. The water comes from the combustion of the gas. Mine drips water into the drain whether I'm running the air conditioning or the heat.

Comment: @Jon that may be the case. It seems to happen a lot for a day or two then very infrequent.

Comment: "...a lot for a day or two then very infrequent"... Sounds more like you have an ejector pump than a sewage pump.  What else feeds water into it beside the furnace... washing machine, bath vanity, kitchen sink, shower, stool?  Do you get any food waste, tp & bodily waste, or other solids in there?  I expect not, which points to an it being an ejector pump instead of a grinder.  You probably have a high efficiency furnace that's draining condensate into there as Jon mentioned, perfectly normal.

Comment: I believe only a shower, bathroom sink and toilet feed it, as well as the air conditioner condensate. Our furnace is electric, so not too sure there what would be the water draw? The laundry is on main floor and wouldn’t feed into this pump, only basement bathroom to raise the waste water to the overhead sewage pipe to the septic tank.

Answer (score 0):

There are two basic types of sewage pumps in residential applications, ejector pumps and grinder pumps, the difference has to do with where you are pumping the sewage, not so much what the sewage contains. Grinder pumps are for high head situations and/or where you are pumping into a pressurized system, ejector pumps are for low head gravity fed sewer systems. But depending on which type this is, the need to "run on" for 4-6 seconds can either be a necessity or a looming catastrophe! If you don't know the system you have, you might want to have a pro come out and find out, then explain it to you for future reference.

Comment: We are on a septic system and it pumps only about 7-8’ up to the main discharge line. The pump brand is a Burcam.